# Any complete example for express-jwt?

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

I want to use express-jwt in my express node application but I can not find any examples which demonstrate signing-in part.

Any help please?

Comment: Thank you Suhail for doing a google search for me. :)
If you look at first example, there is no express-jwt being used. and in the second one, I can't find the the most important part of the process: sign-in.
I had seen these links before posting the question here.

Comment: Suhail sent you good examples, which enough to try jwt. Or maybe you not completely describe your purpose. In common case, user makes login/signIn request, server check credentials(email, password for example) and send back to client jwt-token. Then each time when logged client want to get some protected data, he need add this token for each request(in header for example)

Comment: While the question is not on topic for SO, it's such a shame that there isn't a good answer to it because the examples for `express-jwt` are bordering on useless.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you try to understand the principle of JWT's and how they are passed between server and client and matched server-side against a secret - here's the [doc](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

[image]

The payload can be any arbitrary user data - i.E.: just a username or id

Basically you need a service that generates a token on successful authentication (when the user logs in with the proper credentials, i.E.: usr & pwd) and create an additional header with the token to be used in further requests to the server.

For [jwt-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-express) you obviously need to install the package (same as with jsonwebtoken) like:

```
npm install jwt-express --save
```

then initialize it like:

```
var jwt = require('jwt-express');
app.use(jwt.init('secret'));
```

from the docs:

> The jwt.init() function returns a middleware function for Express so
> it must be called inside app.use(). It will automatically read in the
> JWT from either the cookie or the Authorization header (configured by
> you) and add a JWT object to the Request object (req). It will also
> add the jwt() method to the Response object (res) to create / store
> JWTs. jwt.init() must be called before any other jwt method.

These are you options:

- cookie: (string) The name of the cookie (default: 'jwt-express')
- cookieOptions: (object) Options to use when storing the cookie (default: {httpOnly: true})
- cookies: (boolean) If true, will use cookies, otherwise will use the Authorization header (default: true)
- refresh: (boolean) Indicates if the JWT should be refreshed and stored every request (default: true)
- reqProperty: (string) The property of req to populate (default: 'jwt')
- revoke: (function) jwt.revoke() will call this function (default: function(jwt) {})
- signOptions: (object) Options to use when signing the JWT (default: {})
- stales: (number) Milliseconds when the jwt will go stale (default: 900000 (15 minutes))
- verify: (function) Additional verification. Must return a boolean (default: function(jwt) {return true})
- verifyOptions: (object) Options to use when verifying the JWT (default: {})

The rest of the logic is up to you to code, but my examples should give you a fair idea how to manage jwt's in your application..

Here is an example how I implemented jwt via jsonwebtoken:

```
 // INFO: Function to create headers, add token, to be used in HTTP requests
  createAuthenticationHeaders() {
    this.loadToken(); // INFO: Get token so it can be attached to headers
    // INFO: Headers configuration options
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // INFO: Format set to JSON
        'authorization': this.authToken // INFO: Attach token
      })
    });
  }

  // INFO: Function to get token from client local storage
  loadToken() {
    this.authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');; // Get token and assign to variable to be used elsewhere
  }
```

and some functionality to store the user-status i.E.:

```
 // INFO: Function to store user's data in client local storage
 storeUserData(token, user) {
   localStorage.setItem('token', token); // INFO: Set token in local storage
   localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)); // INFO: Set user in local 
  storage as string
      this.authToken = token; // INFO: Assign token to be used elsewhere
      this.user = user; // INFO: Set user to be used elsewhere
    }
```

and a logout function to destroy the token in the local storage, i.E.:

```
 // INFO: Function for logging out
 logout() {
this.authToken = null; // INFO: Set token to null
   this.user = null; // INFO: Set user to null
   localStorage.clear(); // INFO: Clear local storage
 }
```

In case you use npm's [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), you can set the ttl of the token when generating it:

```
const token = jwt.sign({ id: idDB }, "secret", { expiresIn: '24h' });
```

or whatever ttl you desire, the string "secret" refers to the secret that's matched against the server.

Comment: This is my job saver thank you <3

Comment: @princebillyGK You are welcome ;)

Comment: The link to jwt-express labeled as express-jwt is somewhat misleading.

Comment: Thx for the hint, @WillSadler - I'll correct that immediately ;)