# Can't get basic authentication in node.js/request module to work with PUT or POST request

Tags: node.js

I am trying to call a REST API endpoint from node.js, using the 'request'module. I keep getting a 401 invalid credentials response. Code is as follows:

```
 var q =  {
        'boothNumber':'1400',
        'databaseName':'demo',
        'exhibitorId':'T19',
        'comment':'N/A'
    };

    var options = {
        url: 'https://api2.e-----d.com',
        path: '/edgewebapi/ACTDev2/booths/hold',
        method: 'PUT',
        //headers: headers,
        headers: { 'Authorization':'Basic VUdFUTdDZkY6RmJsb0QyWiQ='},
        body: JSON.stringify(q)
    }
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('Request successful.');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error = ' + error) ;
        }
    })
```

I have read every post on this site to try to solve it, tried every suggestion, including the 'auth' option below (in a headers object):

I tried using a headers object (below):

```
var headers = {
    'Accept':        'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic VUdFUTdDZkY6RmJsb0QyWiQ='
    /*
    'auth': {
        'user': 'UGEQ7CfF',
        'pass': 'FbloD2Z$',
        'sendImmediately': false
        }
    */
    }
```

I retried using axios, code below, and everything works. (I really need to keep using the request module though, because I am using this in AWS Lambda and the axios causes me other issues...):

```
axios.put(
'https://api2.e---d.com/edgewebapi/ACTDev2/booths/hold?boothNumber=1400&databaseName=demo&exhibitorId=T19',
{},
{ headers : {'Authorization': 'Basic VUdFUTdDZkY6RmJsb0QyWiQ=' } }
).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.status);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Can anyone help by providing the correct code to do this? I have spent days trying to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: If I find time the next couple of days, I'll try to post a working solution regarding your question. For now you can have a look at my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364199/any-complete-example-for-express-jwt/52721909#52721909) - maybe it'll give you a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks iLuvLogic. I looked at that, but I can't see how it is related to my problem.