# What is the best way to automatically generate new tokens from refresh tokens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

Hey guys I'm new to react and I'm building an app that uses jwt tokens and refresh tokens, my tokens last for 15 minutes so I need to refresh it in between without the user knowing, my current solution is to use setInterval(fn, 10 minutes)

```
const regenToken = async()=>{
    if(!token){
        return;
    }
    console.log(token);
    const mainTokenExp = jwt.decode(token).exp;
    if(mainTokenExp <= Date.now()/1000){
        //main token has expired
        const newToken = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/user/token", {
            token:reToken,
        })
        token = newToken.data.accessToken;
        console.log(token)
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
    }
}

let intrId = setInterval(regenToken, 10(60*1000));
```

I know this is not the optimal way to do this. what is the standard(widely used) way to implement this?

Comment: Maybe this question can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531731/how-to-refresh-jwt-tokens-in-react-js-application

Comment: Get a new token the first time it's detected to have expired during the normal user flow.