# React Router params maximum length

Tags: reactjs, react-router

is there a way to change the maximum length of a param in React Router? I want to pass a sequence of about 300 characters from url to my app, but when exceeding certain length I get a 400.

Comment: jwt token is security token and you should not pass it in url

Comment: First of all you shouldn't pass a jwt in the params, you send it in the header back and forward with each request.. Second, params are limited by the browsers, so no - you can't exceed max-lenght.. For an example of the proper use of JWT you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364199/any-complete-example-for-express-jwt/52721909#52721909)

Comment: Well, I have a very specific use-case for that matter and I'm aware of how jwt works and what's it for. 

As for the browser limitations as far as I know they go up to url length as large as 2000 characters. The token I use is merely 300 + the domain which does not exceed 50, so I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with the browser (see google query strings for example)